# How to include \r\n when trying to do a Get request?

Tags: c#, get, httpclient

One of the servers that I'm trying to request on have \r\n in the string. These new lines are clearly visible when you try to get the request via the browser or tools such as Postman. However when I do try to get the string programatically by code, I don't see the \r\n. Why is this or is it even possible to retrieve the \r\n?

```
public async Task<TResponse> GetAsync(string uri)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var content = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(content);
}
```

Response should look like this in which the formatting is needed to be preserved:
[image]

Comment: \r\n is exist when you get the string pragmatically by code but remove it virtually. but in browser they not removed. or re-formatted

Comment: So what does `responses[0].response` look like? What do you mean by "preserve", **exactly**? They will be present in your string, but as actual newline characters.

Comment: Oh what I mean is the \r\n included in the response will be preserved. What I'm getting is a full text of the response without the \r\n after I deserialize the content

Comment: When I try to print the deserialized response, It's not actually formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to preserve the carriage returns by using `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`
to the response that I receive.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

If yuor browser or postman let you see the "new lines" probably is because they make you see the formatted json. To be sure of this try with a lower-level tool like curl or wget.

If with curl or wget you will see a json without new lines than it's just a matter of format.
All you have to do is to deserialize (as you are already doing) and re-Serialize the object with

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserializedObject, Formatting.Indented)
```

Comment: How to preserve the \r\n when deserializing it? Is it possible?

Comment: did you do the curl call? can you show us the output?

Comment: Added an image above for the part of the response that needs the formatting preserved

Comment: what browser are you using? chrome or firefox? which tab are you examining?

Comment: I'm using chrome. I'm trying to get the data using my sample program, when I dedug the deserialized "response" i don't get the \r\n